# Rewards normalising in reinforcement learning

Tags: deep-learning, reinforcement-learning

I have 20 copies of an [environment](https://github.com/Unity-Technologies/ml-agents/blob/master/docs/Learning-Environment-Examples.md#reacher) that gets a reward of 0.1 when it reaches it target and 0 otherwise.

What I want to do is make sense of how to normalise the rewards. Suppose I run the environment for 300 time steps. So the reward matrix is of size 300x20.

I usually normalise by doing:

```
discounted_rewards = torch.zeros_like(rewards, dtype=torch.float32, device=device)
for t in reversed(range(len(rewards))):
    running_add = rewards[t] + discount * running_add
    discounted_rewards[t] = running_add

mean = discounted_rewards.mean(0, keepdim=True)
std = discounted_rewards.std(0, keepdim=True) + 1e-10
discounted_rewards = (discounted_rewards - mean) / std
```

However, when I was doing an assignment I normalised the mean across the environments and not timesteps. i.e.

```
mean = discounted_rewards.mean(1, keepdim=True)
std = discounted_rewards.std(1, keepdim=True) + 1e-10
discounted_rewards = (discounted_rewards - mean) / std
```

and this seems to train faster. Was using PPO if it helps.

So my questions are:

1. Which way are you supposed to normalise?
2. I read this [SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49801638/normalizing-rewards-to-generate-returns-in-reinforcement-learning) which mentions that normalisation "doesn't mess with the sign of the gradient". However, if the reward is less than the mean it does change the sign of the gradient doesn't it?
3. (optional) why does normalisation even work?